# Missing characters in zsh; powerline

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, vim-powerline, powerline

I just installed oh-my-zsh and it is everything I ever wanted. But when I try to use some of the more fancy themes. It looks like I am missing some characters. This is what it looks like.

[image]

when it should look like this:

[image]

I have tried intalling the [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

EXTRA INFO: the theme I am trying using is "bullet-train"

Comment: You need proper font, which contains required glyphs. You have to choose the font in your terminal application.

Comment: Man, four out of the last fifty zsh questions are about powerline, and three of them, this one included, are font problems (basically duplicates of each other, except we have a nice gallery of non-working screenshots now). This thing should be burned.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. upon inspection this is a duplicate, but with a more basic solution. That was not mentioned anywhere else. Which is, after installing the Powerline fonts, manually apply them to the terminal.
In iTerm2: iterm > preferences > profiles > text > Regular font & non ASCII font.
in Terminal : Terminal > preferences > profiles > text > fonts